# JavaScript function for calculating is not working?

Tags: javascript, calculation

this is my html input field

```
<input type="number" id="t1">
<br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="getvalue()">calculate</button>
<br />
<div id="l1">change<div>
```

this is my script

```
<script>
function getvalue() {
  var l = document.getElementById('l1');
  var c = document.getElementById('t1').value;
  var lc = c + 200;
  var tax =  2.1;
  var tot = lc * tax;
  l.innerHTML=tot;
}
</script>
```

and in text box i enter 10 so result is 441   this is the  calculation   10+200 = 210
then 210*2.1 = 441

but in text box i enter 10 and click button i got 21420

the problem is  `var lc = c + 200;` this is not calculate correct here its work 10200

and i try this method also  `var x = 200;`   `var lc = c + x;` this is also i got 10200 how can i fix this?

Comment: You're combining strings, you need to convert them to integers.

Comment: Or numbers, if not integer. Use `Number(..)`

Comment: `parseFloat(c) + 200` or  `parseInt(c) + 200` value is string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` of value in `input number` is `string`.

```js
var val = document.getElementById('t1').value ;
console.log( typeof val ) ;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="t1">
```

So you must convert to number like this:

```
var lc = Number(c) + 200 ;
//OR
var lc = parseInt(c) + 200 ;
//OR
var lc = parseFloat(c) + 200 ;
```

```js
function getvalue() {
  var l = document.getElementById('l1');
  var c = document.getElementById('t1').value;
  var lc = Number(c) + 200;
  var tax =  2.1;
  var tot = lc * tax;
  l.innerHTML=tot;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="t1">
<br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="getvalue()">calculate</button>
<br />
<div id="l1">change  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the type of input is `number`, actually the value is of type string. That's why string concatenation is happening.

You can check the type of value with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.

To perform the intended arithmetic operation, you have to convert the value to number.

**Please Note:**  It is better to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content.

```
var c = Number(document.getElementById('t1').value);
```

```js
function getvalue() {
  var l = document.getElementById('l1');
  var c = document.getElementById('t1').value;
  console.log(typeof(c)); //string
  var lc = Number(c) + 200;
  var tax =  2.1;
  var tot = lc * tax;
  l.textContent = tot;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="t1"> <br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="getvalue()">calculate</button> <br />
<div id="l1">change  <div>
```

Comment: don't you think closing bracket should be after .value?

Comment: undefined
var c = Number(document.getElementById('t1')).value;
l.innerHTML=lc ;
undefined error

Comment: thz 

var c = Number(document.getElementById('t1').value);  now its ok